# ¿Cómo iterar un array dinamico en react sin saber los nombres de lo que viene dentro?

Tags: json, reactjs

Estoy tratando de iterar un arreglo :

```
data: [
        {
            "fecha_modificacion": "2021-01-27 17:17:48",
            "usuario_modificacion": "lugomez",
            "dato_anterior": {
                "clave_territorio": "USA",
                "clave_clasificacion": "01",
                "clave_forma_de_pago": "C007"
            },
            "dato_nuevo": {
                "clave_territorio": "AS",
                "clave_forma_de_pago": "CCON"
            }
        },
        {
            "fecha_modificacion": "2021-01-29 17:42:24",
            "usuario_modificacion": "lugomez",
            "dato_anterior": {
                "amount": "0.0000",
                "usuario_creacion": "jalcantar"
            },
            "dato_nuevo": {
                "amount": 0
            }
        }
]
```

si se dan cuenta lo que viene dentro de dato anterior y lo que viene dentro de dato_nuevo no es igual, esto pasa por que es para una tabla de un log de cambios y nunca se lo que va a llegar dentro de dichos nodos.

Estoy haciendo una tabla para mostrar esto pero me da error.

```
<tbody>
   {
     this.props.logs.data.map((item, index)=>{
      return(
        <tr key={index}>
              <td>{  }</td>
              <td>
                  { 
                   (()=>{
                    item.dato_anterior.map((dt,i)=>{
                        return (
                          <ul>
                             <li>{dt.i}</li>
                          </ul>
                         );
                    })
                    })    
                     ()
                  }
                   </td>
                        <td>
                          { 
                           (()=>{
                                item.dato_anterior.map((dt,i)=>{
                                   return (
                                       <ul>
                                          <li>{dt.i}</li>
                                       </ul>
                                   );
                                })
                               })    
                               ()
                            </td>
                   <td>{ item.usuario_modificacion }</td>
                   <td>{ item.fecha_modificacion }</td> 
                 </tr>
                  )
              })
            }
   </tbody>
```

lo que necesito es mapear lo que esta dentro de dato_nuevo y dato_anterior aun sin saber que es lo que viene adentro.

Comment: ¿Qué error te tira?

Comment: Ya publique mi solucion... solo me falta darle formato al resultado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solo utilice Object.values para traer los valores:

```
<tr key={index}>
     <td>{ Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item.dato_anterior).sort() }</td>
     <td>
         <ul>
              {
               <li>{Object.values(item.dato_anterior)}</li>
              }
         </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
          <ul>
             {
              <li>{Object.values(item.dato_nuevo)}</li>    
             }
         </ul>
   </td>
   <td>{ item.usuario_modificacion }</td>
   <td>{ item.fecha_modificacion }</td> 
</tr>
```

Solo me falta darle formato..
Gracias